# Tracing MFC message handling

Tags: c++, debugging, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

Trying to upgrade an MFC app to use the new MFC feature pack, we are loosing the messages from a context menu. The menu appears and can be clicked, but the message seems not to be handled anywhere. We overrode OnCmdMsg() in lots of places but to no avail, the context menu's command message are not caught.

Is there a way, tool, or approach to trace messages?
Any other ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try SPY++

[> ...can be found on the Programs or All Programs menu in Windows. Click Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0, and then click Visual Studio Tools.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx)

> 

Provides a graphical view of the processes, threads, windows, and window messages of a system. For more information, click Help in the tool.

I explain more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663489/software-to-monitor-events-fired-from-code/664845#664845) about Spy++ for 2005.